# Projects are not synchronizing and the tasks are not loading while refreshing the gradle projects

Tags: gradle, multi-project

Gradle version - 4.2.1

I have the project structure like below. There is no error in gradle log but still the tasks not loaded.

My project structure

```
-root
    -Project1 
     -build.gradle
    -buildProject
     -settings.gradle
     -build.gradle
    -Project2 
     -build.gradle
        -Subproject1
         -build.gradle
        -Subproject2
         -build.gradle
        -Subproject3
         -build.gradle
```

settings.gradle

```
includeFlat 'Project1'
includeFlat 'Project2'
include 'Project2:Subproject1'
include 'Project2:Subproject2'
include 'Project2:Subproject3'
```

Info level log message

```
Evaluating project ':Project2:Subproject1' using build file 'D:\User\worksapce\Project2\Subproject1\build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':Project2:Subproject2' using build file 'D:\User\worksapce\Project2\Subproject2\build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':Project2:Subproject3' using build file 'D:\User\worksapce\Project2\Subproject3\build.gradle'.
All projects evaluated.
```

After the above log message nothing is happening. what will be the next steps that gradle should perform to load all the tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of the issue and fixed. The issue is some jar conflict in gradle build file. But the gradle havn't thrown any exception explicitly. I checked in Error Log window in eclipse and found that. The error severity was warning. I have fixed the conflict and then all the tasks loaded in gradle tasks.